# C: pointer questions

Tags: c, pointers

Two questions on the following codes:

1. What is the difference between with and without `malloc()` statement:

   ```
   p = (char *) malloc (20 * sizeof(char) );
   ```

   Is it just the difference of memory location? Pointer variable '`p`' is in STACK without that statement and in HEAP with that statement?
2. Why statement is

   ```
   printf("%s\n", p);
   ```

   not

   ```
   printf("%s\n", *p);
   ```

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   char movie[] = "forrest gump";
   char *p;

   p = (char *) malloc (20 * sizeof(char) );
   p = movie;

   printf("%p\n", p);
   printf("%p\n", movie);
   printf("%s\n", p); // to print "forrest gump"

   free(p);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: strings are nul-terminated arrays of characters. `*p` would pass printf a single character.  `p` passes a pointer to the start of the string

Comment: And you cant use `free(p)` as the pointer has been modified from the original `malloc( )` assignment. This could cause a runtime error.

Comment: Ryan: thanks, "printf("%s\n", *p);" would cause program to crash.

Comment: Shaurya: thanks, you seem right, how to free up the memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Question 1

The code with line number comments added:

```
char movie[] = "forrest gump";                 // 1
char *p;                                       // 2

p = (char *) malloc (20 * sizeof(char) );      // 3
p = movie;                                     // 4

printf("%p\n", p);                             // 5
printf("%p\n", movie);                         // 6
printf("%s\n", p); // to print "forrest gump"  // 7

free(p);                                       // 8
```

I will ignore that the return value from `malloc()` is not checked, and I'm not phased by casts on the return value from `malloc()` as long as you get told by your compiler if you omit the declaration for `malloc()` — but there are plenty who would disagree with that.  The `* sizeof(char)` is not necessary and might be better written as `* sizeof(*p)`.

The code has a memory leak, and it exhibits undefined behaviour because of the memory leak.

Line 1 is fine.  Line 2 is likewise fine, though it would be possible to initialize the variable by combining it with line 3.

Line 3 is safe in this context, but the fixed size of the allocation would be a problem in other contexts.

Line 4 is a major problem.  It is the leak.  You've just trampled over the only pointer to the memory returned by `malloc()`, so that memory is irrevocably lost.  Granted, this program will exit shortly (if it doesn't crash first), but in general, that's bad.  You should have written:

```
strcpy(p, movie);
```

or perhaps:

```
memmove(p, movie, sizeof(movie));
```

Line 5 will print the address stored in `p`.  As written, that's the address of `movie` because of the assignment in line 4.  Arguably, it should be written with a cast since the `%p` format specifier takes a `void *`:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)p);
```

In practice, you'll get away with it everywhere when `p` is a `char *`.  I learned to program on a machine (in the days before there was a C standard) where the bit representation of a `char *` address was different from the `anything_bigger *` address for the same memory location.  On such a machine, if the code was dealing with `struct Something *` or even `int *`, the cast to `void *` would be necessary.

Line 6 produces the same output as line 5, and has the same caveats.

Line 7 is fine and prints out the data that `p` points at, which is the data that `movie` points at too.

Line 8 is where you invoke undefined behaviour.  Because of the assignment in line 4, you're trying to free unallocated space, which is a serious disaster.  It can often lead to a crash; it is never a good idea.

The code should plausibly read:

```
char movie[] = "forrest gump";
char *p = malloc(sizeof(movie)); // or: char *p = malloc(strlen(movie) + 1);
if (p != 0)
{
    strcpy(p, movie);
    printf("%p\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", movie);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    free(p);
}
```

#### Question 2

Your question 2 is about:

```
printf("%s\n",  p);
printf("%s\n", *p);
```

The first is correct.  `p` is a `char *`, and the `%s` conversion specification expects a `char *`.  The second is incorrect because `*p` is a `char`, but `%s` expects a `char *`.  It gets, instead, a small integer (102 if your code set is based on ASCII) and tries to treat that as an address.  This does not work; it usually causes a crash as the whole of the first page of memory (1 KiB or 4 KiB) is usually mapped as invalid.

You could use:

```
printf("%c\n", *p);
```

which would print `f`.

Comment: I mean **p** has a address after **char *p;** and then it points to **movie** by **p = movie;**.

Comment: If you remove line 3 (the `malloc()` line), you also need to remove line 8 (the `free()` line).  Other than that, though, yes — everything is OK.  Always make sure you can identify the `free()` for every `malloc()`.

Comment: Yes, **free()** should be removed as well.  After **p = movie;**, **p** address changes, what is the difference between this change and the change with **p = (char *) malloc (20 * sizeof(char) );**.

Comment: The main difference is where `p` points to.  In the case with `malloc()`, it points to an area on 'the heap', whereas after `p = movie;`, it points to an area on 'the stack'.  In the case with `malloc()`, you need to preserve the pointer so the space it points at can be returned for reuse with `free()`; in the case with `p = movie;`, you don't have to preserve the pointer in `p` because `movie` points to the same memory, and you don't need to free the memory because `movie` was not dynamically allocated.

Comment: Also, the address that `p` points at changes; the address of `p` itself does not change.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mostly, yes. `malloc` allocates heap space and returns a pointer to it. When the function enters, stack space is allocated for any local variables.  In this case, that's 13 bytes for array `movie` ("forrest gump" with a null terminator, maybe more depending on alignment issues and character widths). `movie` will be initialized with the specified data.  If the string were longer, it would be copied from a copy in the constant data set up by the compiler (until the last decade or so, it would have done so with any string, but these days it appears that at least some compilers initialize short strings directly with machine code). There is also space for the pointer `p` allocated on the stack.
2. `printf` defines the behavior of `%s` as expecting a pointer.  Putting a 'string' on the stack (rather than a pointer to it) would seriously complicate the implementation of the language because they are variable in size.  Strings are not special constructs in C as they are in many other languages.  In C they are just an array of characters terminated by a `null` or zero byte (and only the string library functions care about that—the compiler doesn't, except possibly for error checking).

Comment: Thanks, James.  For Q1, I can understand it. For Q2,  does *p mean what p is pointing to? that should be "forrest gump", but the program actually crashes.

Comment: Re 1: The string `"forrest gump"` is copied into an array of exactly the right size (13 bytes) on the stack. The initializer is copied from somewhere (the compiler knows), but the array `movie` is a local, modifiable character array. There's no storage for the `movie` pointer; you cannot change the address of `movie`. This is complete contrast to `char *film = "Saturday Night Fever";` where the data is in read-only memory and there's a pointer on the stack.  You can change what `film` points to by pointing to another string (e.g. `film = movie;`) but you can't change the content of the string.

Comment: @YHH: `*p` Is only the character `f``, and that's all that will be put on the stack.  When `printf` runs, it will attempt to turn that into a pointer, which will use either adjacent stack variables or adjacent uninitialized bytes as the pointer which is why it crashes (theoretically it might not crash under certain circumstances, but they would very rare, especially on a 64-bit machine).